# npm run запуск команд по очереди

Tags: javascript, webpack, npm

есть 3 команды 
1 сборка webpack
2 запуск express
3 запуск electron приложения
подскажите как написать 1 команду что бы запускать их все по очереди

```
"scripts": {
    "electron": "electron .",
    "watch": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "dev": "start npm run watch && start npm run electron"
  },
```

Comment: Windows или linux?

Answer (score 3):

```
"dev": "npm run build && npm run watch && npm run electron"
```

где `&&` - последовательные задачи, а `&` - параллельные (`&` только для UNIX подобных систем)

Comment: Это с каких это пор `&` стало параллельным?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://frontender.info/task_automation_with_npm_run/

Comment: @Qwertiy также забыл добавить, что только для UNIX подобных систем

Comment: Хм.. `&` в конце команды для отдельного запуска там был, да, а вот между - что-то не видел. Или тоже можно? В любом случае, в Windows амперсанд так не работает.